# Limit occurrence of records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have created a view that combines two tables to show a list of email addresses and location details i.e.

Email Address One  |  Location 1
Email Address One  |  Location 2
Email Address One  |  Location 3
Email Address One  |  Location 4
Email Address Two  |  Location 1
Email Address Two  |  Location 2

This loops through a few hundred emails.

Unfortunately I need to limit each email address so only 5 records for each are selected - at present there are more than 70 records being returned for some records.

Is it possible to limit the number of each email address being returned to a maximum of 5 for example?

Comment: How do you diferentiate between the ones you want to show and the ones you want to hide?

Comment: They are sorted by distance with the top 5 closest being selected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a rank to each email address in your return result, E.g

```
1 | Email Address One | Location 1
2 | Email Address One | Location 2
3 | Email Address One | Location 3
4 | Email Address One | Location 4
1 | Email Address Two | Location 1
2 | Email Address Two | Location 2
```

once you have that rank, you can add a where rank < 5. if you use a group clause to create the rank you will have to use a having clause e.g having rank < 5.

Unfortunately I don't know your table's layout or your query to create the said results, therefore I cannot help you create the rank.

This has not been tested but might do the trick (assuming id is locations's unique identifier):

```
select 
    user.email AS email,
    locations.locationname AS locationname,
    count(A.id) AS rank
from 
    locations
    join user on (location.department = user.department)
    join locations A on A.id < locations.id
group by
    locations.id
having
    rank < 5
order by
    locations.id
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - the view query is below:<br> 
select user.email AS email,, locations.locationname AS locationname from (locations join user on((location.department = user.department)))

Answer (score 0):

How about using MySQL's LIMIT command?  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html.

Comment: Would this just limit the overall rows returned?

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I need to still select every email address but only 5 locations for each

Comment: It would be best to post the actual table schemas and the query that's not working to make it more clear.

Comment: OK - The query that generates the view is below:

Comment: select `user`.`email` AS `email`,,
`locations`.`locationname` AS `locationname`
from (`locations` join `user` on((`location`.`department` = `user`.`department`)))

Comment: how about: SELECT user.email AS email, locations.locationname AS locationname from user JOIN (select locationname,department from locations LIMIT 5) AS locations;