# MySQL limiting rows in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql

i have a database with 3 tables in a many-to-many relationship. one is the **books**, the other is the **authors** and the third is their **junction** (used to join the two). the database is **MySQL**

*a book can be made by many authors, and authors make many books.*

[image]

now i want to get the books (with authors) like say 8 books at a time. i made this query:

```
//first table
SELECT * FROM `books`

//join the junction 
LEFT JOIN books_authors ON books.book_id = books_authors.book_id

//join the authors
LEFT JOIN authors ON books_authors.author_id = authors.author_id

//limit to 8, start at S
limit S, 8
```

works fine when one-to-one. but when a book *has more authors*, like say 3 each, the sql result will have `8 x 3` rows in total (due to the 2D nature of the result) for all the details. but the query still clips it to 8 - i don't get all the details.

how to get 8 books with all details?

Comment: is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092641/limit-occurrence-of-records-in-mysql

Comment: what SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could limit the number of books in a subquery:

```
select  * 
from    (
        select  *
        from    books
        limit   6, 7
        ) b
left join 
        ba ba
on      b.book_id = ba.book_id
left join 
        authors a
on      ba.author_id = a.author_id
```

Comment: I think that it will not work if you have to set a where clause on authors or ba

Answer (score 2):

Do not know what SQL features does your server support, but there are windowing functions that are supported by many. Essentially, you compute a sequential number to every book by given author in a particular ordering, and select only these having that number less or equal than 8 (for some value of 8). The numbering is provided by the function ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT * FROM (     
  SELECT a.author_id, b.book_id, a.name, b.title, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.author_id ORDER BY b.title) book_seq
    FROM author a 
    LEFT JOIN book b on a.author_id = b.author_id) dummy
  WHERE book_seq <= 8
```

Above, `ORDER BY b.title` defines the ordering in which you select the 8 minimal book records.

*EDIT:* mySQL does not support ROW_NUMBER(), so my answer does not apply as it is. There is [an interesting article](http://briansteffens.com/2011/07/19/row_number-partition-and-over-in-mysql/) with examples on simulating ROW_NUMBER with OVER (PARTITION) in mySQL.

Comment: you don't have analytic functions in mysql yet.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: Bummer. I did not know he was using mySQL.

Comment: sorry for that, i forgot that SQL has different "flavors". i updated my question after realizing that. you can edit your answer.

Comment: @Joseph: Does the article I linked to makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head, I'd guess you could try something like

```
select * 
from ( select * from books limit s, 8 ) booksLimited
join books_authors on booksLimited.book_id = books_authors.book_id
join authors on books_authors.author_id = authors.book_id
```

But I'm not going to go to the effort of installing mySQL just to try this out for you.  If it doesn't work, comment on it and I'll delete the answer.